# UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: and new section count: with userInfo (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, debugging, core-data

I haven't seen this error before, and I did a search as to why it may be happening but couldn't find any info on it:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section
>   count: 0 with userInfo (null)

Does anyone know what might be happening here? I am not sure about the "internal bug" part - does this error indicate a problem with my code or a bug in UITableView?

Comment: I guess its problem in your NSFetchedResultsController delegate method controllerDidChangeContent ...in this method data-source isn't got expected UITableView want.

Comment: I've same error, but I don't use NSFetchedResultsController, just             `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath] ...)` and I've turn around by **never saying section = 0** in `override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)`, always keep at least 1, maybe empty

Comment: #grominet, don't do that, instead delete your section and not your row if it is the last row of the section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephan already mentioned this in a comment on the original question but I thought it was worth sharing some code. This answer was actually sourced from a comment made by user `GERUB` on a thread on the apple dev forums found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9964

```
if tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) == 1{  
    tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)  
}else{  
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)  
}
```

I have tested this inside of the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method implementations and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use this NSFetchedResultsController in multiple UITableView. If so, that's the cause. Use one NSFetchedResultsController for one UITableView. Do not just switch queries when switching views.

Answer (score 0):

When using CoreData with the NSFetchedResultsController you don't really need to mess about with checking to see if it's the last item in a section that you are deleting.

You can simply utilise another of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate's methods: `controller(: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex: Int, for: NSFetchedResultsChangeType)`.

This delegate method will specifically inform you when a section is added or removed and you can then act accordingly, allowing you to have simpler code.