# Unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0 with FetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

In my view controller I have an implemented fetchedResultsController and everything works fine (showing rows, several sections, fetching etc).

But I'm getting an error when trying to update or delete the last row in section, (When I'm saying the "last row", I mean that there is only one row left in the section). If there are more than one row in the section, when I update it's value (in Core Data), it happens with no errors. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942591/uitableview-internal-bug-unable-to-generate-a-new-section-map-with-old-section), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951169/deleting-the-last-section-of-a-uitableview-causes-an-exception) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35241069/deleting-last-row-from-uitableview-crash-with-nsinternalinconsistencyerror) but it didn't helped me (the solution is outdated), and I have not found any solution to my problem on StackOverflow and on the internet. I need help with this. I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 and Swift 3.

Here is the error I get when trying to make updates to the "Only" row in any section of a tableView:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  
An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:. 
 UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 
1 and new section count: 0 with userInfo (null)
```

I'm using this method to return the number of sections:

```
  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

           return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 0

    }
```

This is the method to get the number of rows:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {

            let currentSection = sections[section]
            return currentSection.numberOfObjects
        }

        return 0

    }
```

I also have the following methods in my view Controller:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}



func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .delete:
            guard let path = indexPath
                else { return }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [path],
                                 with: .none)

        case .insert:
            guard let path = newIndexPath
                else { return }
            tableView.insertRows(at: [path],
                                 with: .automatic)

        case .move:

            guard let _ = indexPath,
                let _ = newIndexPath
                else { return }

            if indexPath != newIndexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .none)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .none)
            }


        case .update:

            guard let path = indexPath
                else { return }

            tableView.reloadRows(at: [path], with: .none) // No blinking with .none

        }

    }
```

I've tried to change numberOfSections method to return 1 section if there are no sections,

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

```
if self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count == 0 {
    return 1
} else {
     return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 1
}
```

}

but I I'm getting another error in this case.

```
  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.
  *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray with userInfo (null)
```

Comment: Some time crash happens because of `beginupdate` and `endupdate`. Remove and check that (I don't know exactly why)

Comment: @user3589771 I've tried to delete  self.tableView.beginUpdates() and self.tableView.endUpdates() calls, but this doesn't solve the issue, leads to another crash: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts I've found a solution:

After adding this method I have no errors:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
            switch type {
            case .insert:
                tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
            case .delete:
                tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex) as IndexSet, with: .fade)
            case .move:
                break
            case .update:
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: This has been giving me headaches for weeks. Thanks for the solution!